# GWT example app and the GWT Designer: what you see is not what you get

Tags: java, gwt, windowbuilder

I am new to GWT. Followed the [GWT docs](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/usingeclipse) to set up the Google plugin and the GWT designer in Eclipse "Juno" (V4.2). Created a Web application with the example code. It runs and displays nicely in Firefox:

[image: GWT example app output in browser]

Then I open the Java class that implements EntryPoint using the WindowBuilder, and the canvas shows something different. The input field label "Please enter your name:" is not visible, and the "Send" button is under the input field, rather than to its right. Screenshot below:

[image: GWT example in WindowBuilder]

Since the whole point in using the GWT designer is to get the layout right visually, it is kind of disconcerting to see it not working in a WYSIWYG manner with the example code.

Question A: Is there a way of fixing this discrepancy? Are there some config files or HTML or CSS that perhaps need to be edited so that the designer's view matches what the browser would display when the example app is running?

Question B: Is the GWT designer working "as advertised" in your everyday practice? Can I trust this tool? If not, what alternatives would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the GWT designer a **pita** tool on eclipse platform which takes memory hogging to whole new level even in comparison to GWT Hosted mode!!!!!

List of [GWT Articles](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUi) from Dev Guide on google.

**Preferre Option at enterprise workplace**

1. HTML/CSS/UIBinder for rich look and feel
2. Handcoded GWT Layouting and Widgets for complex gui behaviour/performance.

**Edit -** **GWT Designer is hardly updated/maintained** - I have seen only 10 odd checkins in a year. I wish i am wrong ( does google team not update the public svn !!! ) - https://code.google.com/p/gwt-designer/source/list

Comment: Could you please provide some more details on why GWT Designer is a PITA tool? Is it only the memory usage or are there other aspects you are not happy with / any other caveats to be aware of? Thanks

Comment: Memory , Buggy and Usability ( compared to netbeans swing , .net studio ) is pita. It does not even work well with custom themes, custom widgets, uibinder etc. We just gave up after 3 months of usage ( This was a year ago ).

Comment: Updated post to mention that GWT Designer has hardly had 10 checkins in a year!!!

Answer (score 1):

It becouse in the example project, Gwt inject widgets to existed html. So, you have one part of style in html, and second part in rendered gwt widgets. And it is looks ugly. 
If you will use only gwt style approch (without any html styles, e.t.c), designer will be predictable and totaly wysiwyg.